# Math symbols in math operators

Tags: math-operators

I would like to customize the weak-star limit as a math operator. It should look like `w$^*$-lim`. I don't want to use `w*-lim` or `w^*-lim` because it looks ugly. But when I write

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslim}{w$^*$-lim}
```

I get an error because dollars cannot be used in `\mathrm` mode. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Your question about why MathJax doesn't work here is answered by this meta question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272

Comment: You commented on the meta question that you don't like mathjax not being enabled, I suggest that you use the site for a while longer to see why that is a good policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` obtains a special mathcode inside the AMS math operator setup, but here you want the standard star which is still available as `\ast` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslima}{w^{*}-lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslimb}{w^{\ast}-lim}
\begin{document}
\[\wslima a \quad \wslimb a\]
\end{document}
```

Note the reason for the redefinition is to make it possible to just use  `w*` which is the intended markup here although as you note it does not produce the same symbol (or use the same font) as a normal math `^*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslim}{w*-lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslima}{w^{*}-lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslimb}{w^{\ast}-lim}
\begin{document}
\[\wslim a \quad \wslima a \quad \wslimb a\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Finally someone who reads the question carefully. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @amsmath it also helps that I'm the current maintainer of the package and I had an idea what it was doing without needing to read the question that carefully:-)

Comment: You're the maintainer of the amsmath package? Then you should like my nick. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath actually I was considering asking you to change it, it may be confusing to others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd be interested in this variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslim}{w\raisebox{-1.5pt}{${}^{*} $}\mkern-2mu-lim}

\begin{document}

\[ \wslim f \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote in my question: "I don't want to use `w*-lim` because it looks ugly"...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it. I mainly focused on not having compilation errors. For me the exponent is too high w.r.t. a lowercase letter. I even tried a simple \textsuperscript, but I obtained the same result as with math mode.

Comment: I've modified my code. Is it more like you want?

Comment: @Bernard I vote instead your answer. Nice :-)